# create multiple data frames of one from with the same size

Tags: python, pandas

this is my df:

```
 count  pic_name
 0  0   Training_35668808.jpg
 1  1   Training_92439792.jpg
 2  2   Training_53079763.jpg
 3  3   Training_41634629.jpg
 4  4   Training_19995150.jpg
 ...    ... ...
 95 95  Training_85112475.jpg
 96 96  Training_58545645.jpg
 97 97  Training_36682771.jpg
 98 98  Training_82360956.jpg
 99 99  Training_39750918.jpg
```

It's just a sample of my real df. I want to cut the frame into multiple parts. Let's say three parts.

I tried this:

```
df1 = df_sample.iloc[:33]
df2 = df_sample.iloc[33:,80:]
df3 = df_sample.iloc[80:]
```

Sadly it does not work for the second command. Has anyone an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your second command:

```py
df_sample.iloc[33:80]
```

meaning from index `33` to index `80`.